# Navigate to the JS code from source maps in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, source-maps

Is there any way to navigate to the original JS file from source maps?

I paused my app on a breakpoint; Chrome is showing me source-map-file which is "source mapped from index.js". At that moment I want to navigate to that index.js file, but I can't find a way to do it.

Comment: Did you ever find a way to do this?

Comment: @Barjavel nope, I didn't